# How did Quentin Beck trick S.H.I.E.L.D. and hide his history with Stark Enterprises?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

Despite the fact that they were secretly invaded by Hydra a few years ago, in *Far From Home*, they're working with him taking his word for it?

Comment: There was a secret invasion of Skrulls too...and they aren't that bright.

Comment: I've marked this as a dupe, whilst the title and focus of the _question_ is somewhat different the _answer_ covers this pretty thoroughly from Beck's perspective. It only really misses the Skrull angle but that's already covered here.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - That answer covers the fact that Beck changed his background, but it isn't at clear that the real S.H.I.E.L.D. would've been fooled by that. They easily picked up on [Thor's falsified ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTwNB.jpg) in _Thor (2011)_. Also, Beck claiming to be from another reality was quite a tall story, and I imagine the real S.H.I.E.L.D. would've investigated that more thoroughly than the Skrulls did. So the fact that Beck _never directly interacted_ with the real S.H.I.E.L.D. seems more central in answering this question, than him merely changing his background.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you saw the post-credits scene or not, but it was revealed that the 'Nick Fury' and 'Maria Hill' we saw for most of the film weren't the genuine articles, but rather, the Skrulls, [Talos](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Talos) and [Soren](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Soren), previously seen in *Captain Marvel (2019)*. They were technically working on behalf of the real Nick Fury, but he wasn't keeping a close eye on them, so they were the ones who were fooled, not him or S.H.I.E.L.D..

From the Marvel Wiki page for [Nick Fury's Crew](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Nick_Fury%27s_Crew):

> After Nick Fury was brought back by the Blip, he eventually tasked Talos and Soren to come to Earth and replace him and Maria Hill respectively while he took a leave of absence in space. **In 2024, Quentin Beck and his crew began a campaign to gain public recognition for Beck, who disguised himself as a superhero that would eventually be nicknamed Mysterio. Mysterio successfully manipulated Talos into working together to stop the Elementals from destroying Earth.** In Europe, he intercepted Peter Parker on his school trip to help combat the Elementals.
>
> [...]
>
> Spider-Man and Mysterio met in a final confrontation in London. This conflict signified the appearance of the Elemental Fusion, which attacked the Tower Bridge. Talos provided some assistance as Spider-Man eventually took down Mysterio and exposed his plot, which was to create the Elementals using drones to cast illusions. **Afterwards, Talos contacted Fury and told him that he had given the E.D.I.T.H. glasses to Parker, declining to share details about his misplaced trust in Beck.**